# Recieving Incomplete response using Jersey client. How to keep client to wait for getting complete response

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jersey-client, jersey-1.0

I am creating Jersey client( jersey-client1.8, jersey-core1.8)

```
ClientConfig clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();
Client restClient = Client.create(clientConfig);
WebResource webResource = restClient.resource(serviceURL)
  /*try{  
  Thread.sleep(10000);
} catch(InterruptedException ie){}
*/

ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/xml")
            .header("Authorization", "Basic " + credentials)            
            .get(ClientResponse.class);

//response data 
    if(response.getStatus()== HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
        String responseInXMLString = response.getEntity(String.class);
```

I am receiving the success response. 
Response out in String is:

```
<Entity>
  <field>
  <Name>status</name>
  <Value/>
</field>
```

Here I am not receiving the value of the field 'id'.

When I am doing debug by keeping break point at line:
   `ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/xml")` 
and start debugging line by line then I am getting value for the field 'id'.
 OR 
If I put`thread.sleep(10000)` then I am getting value for the field 'id'.

Please suggest how to handle this to get the complete response.

Comment: Try to run URI in postman. Show us about resources xml format.

Comment: @ atiqkhaled  I have checked same in SOAPUI. Value is available for 'id' in the response.

Comment: My observation is: 
1. When I keep break point at line: `if(response.getStatus()== HttpStatus.SC_OK) {`  and start debugging..
When I am keeping break point at line: `ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/xml")` and start debugging and when I reach the line if(response.getStatus()== HttpStatus.SC_OK) {

Comment: 1. When I put break point at line: `if(response.getStatus()== HttpStatus.SC_OK) {`  n start debug.
Result: value is **not coming** for 'id' field.

2. When I'm put break point at line: `ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/xml")` and start debug'g
When I reach line  `if(response.getStatus()== HttpStatus.SC_OK) {`
Result: values is **coming** for 'id' field.
- I feel. because of debugging  step by step, there is some waiting time to reach line of code: `if(response.getStatus()== HttpStatus.SC_OK) {` Response is completely generated n I'm getting value for 'id' field.

Comment: Ok, Replace your if clause with this code :  `if(response.getStatus() != 200) {
     throw new RuntimeException("Failed http error code :" + response.getStatus());
    }
          String output = response.getEntity(String.class);
    System.out.println(output);` Let me know about output.

Comment: Here is response xml copied from SOAPUI: 
`<Entity>
 <field>
      <Name>start-time</name>
      <id>2017-01-16 20:28:26</id>
    </field> 
 <field>
      <Name>end-time></name>
      <id>2017-01-16 20:28:30</id>
     </field> 
    <field>
      <Name>state</name>
      <id>Finished</id>
    </field> 
 <field>
         <Name>status</name>
         <id>T</id>
 </field>
</Entity>`
In postman/SOAP ui: value of 'id' is coming as T.

Comment: Did you try mine code?

Comment: @ atiqkhaled. Sorry I didnt get you.what code?

Comment: I hv tried ur code, There is NO response err.  Output xml is fine but value for 'id' is not returning. But I tried same url in SOAP,  value for 'id' is coming.

Comment: Observed: Client(I am) is receiving response before response is completely generated from service provider end. Hence it is incomplete.

My client code should wait till the response is completely generated from service end. 
How to do that.

Comment: Your response status is ok means Web-Services produces all required data via HTTP.  However there is a workaround , place this code `Thread.sleep(4000);` before `if` clause. let me know.

Comment: True, If you place the 'Thread.sleep before `if` clause It wont work. bcaz by that time response is already received. But if we place 'Thread.sleep(1000)'  after the code `ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/xml")..` . It is working fine n With this approach Im getting full response n getting vale of the field.

Comment: `ClientConfig clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();`
  `Client restClient = Client.create(clientConfig);`
    `WebResource webResource = restClient.resource(serviceURL)`

    `try{`
      `Thread.sleep(1000);`
   ` }catch(InterruptedExeption ie) {}`

`ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/xml")`
           ` .header("Authorization", "Basic " + credentials)            
            .get(ClientResponse.class);`

`//response data `
  `  if(response.getStatus()== HttpStatus.SC_OK) {`
       ` String responseInXMLString = response.getEntity(String.class);`

Comment: But keeping 'Thread.sleep' is not a good approach.

Comment: Yes , but I said you earlier this is workaround. You have your solution , right? [chat]

Comment: U mean:  Thread.sleep is a solution ?
Nope, I guess, Jersey API might be having functionality for such scenarios. I am searching for that.
So please suggest how to handle this.

Comment: I mean I am looking for a solution to handle this.

Comment: come to chat room [http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109494/friendly-bin] ...

Comment: No having enough reputation for chat

Comment: I just cloned your code on mine system. It works fine. Make sure you just created one Client instance, If you create more than once then remove it. Lets try this code `Client client = Client.create();
    WebResource webResource = client.resource(uri);
ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/xml")
      .header("user-agent", "")                  .get(ClientResponse.class);` Aloha

Comment: Yep I have created one client instance only. It works fine without any error, but response is incomplete.

Comment: ClientResponse response.
That is my query, incomplete- value for field 'id' is not coming in response. 
and it is getting in 'Debug' mobe/SOAP UI/using thread.sleep before this line of code. `webResource.accept("application/xml") `

Comment: Can anybody please suggest  on this. 
**Response is taking time at service provider But client is not waiting for the complete response.**    How to handle this, so that Client should receive completed response.